# how to prevent install both material-ui and @mui for a nested menu that needs the old version

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, nested

How to use nestedMenu imported form "material-ui-nested-menu-item" which is developed by "material-ui" lib (old version), with the its new version  "@mui" without installing both packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a version for Mui 5. Less headache than trying to deal with the dependencies:

[Material UI Nested Menu Item v5 on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-nested-menu)

[Material UI Nested Menu Item v5 Demo](https://mui-nested-menuitem-demo.vercel.app/)

Comment: good job thank you